# tex4ht configure a personal list after the configuraiton of enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, tex4ht

Edit: I use an extension of tex4ht,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

================================

I have defined a customized list `MYLIST` in my `.tex`. this list `MYLIST` is very simple: I copy-pasted the definition of `enumerate` from the file `ltlist.dtx`, I have changed the name `enumerate` into `MYLISTerate` and then I added the lines, in order to have a control over the labels and the spaces and the depth of the enumeration, in the spirit of this good book:
http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/exercises/enumextend.shtml

**Is it possible to have a code which can be put directly into the `.tex` ??**
**I want to define a `html` environment for `MYLIST` which takes into account:**

- **my personal depth of the enumeration**
- **my personal spacings, for each depth of the enumeration**
- **my personal labels, for each depth of the enumeration**

I went into the file `html4.4ht` and look for the configuration of `enumerate`, and I found this which would, I thought, at least compile my list without giving my the depth nor the spacing,  [you notice that I replaced nothing, expect for `@MYLISTdepth`.]:

```
  \ConfigureList{MYLISTerate}%
     {\EndP\HCode{<ol \a:enumerate:\space class="enumerate\expandafter\the\csname @MYLISTdepth\endcsname" \a:LRdir >}\PushMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm=\empty}
     {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm\EndP\HCode{</li></ol>}\ShowPar}
     {\end:itm \gdef\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\DeleteMark}
     {{\Configure{Link}{li}{}{ class="enumerate" id=}{}\let\EndLink=\empty \AnchorLabel }}
```

but when I compile, I get the error

```
Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AfterEndEnvironment' will not work.

))) (d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)) (./alt.aux)
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1]
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\EndP ->\Protect
                 \par:end
l.209 \item L
           orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting i...
 13385 words of node memory still in use:
   15 hlist, 2 rule, 33 disc, 87 glue, 24 kern, 9 penalty, 349 glyph, 58 glue_sp
ec, 1 temp, 4994 if_stack, 1 shape, 4 special, 2 local_par, 1 dir nodes
```

This is my working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\input{preamble}

\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,
SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}

%\altusepackage{etoolbox}




\makeatletter
\newcount\@MYLISTdepth \@MYLISTdepth = 0
\@definecounter{MYLISTi}
\@definecounter{MYLISTii}
\@definecounter{MYLISTiii}
\@definecounter{MYLISTiv}
\def\MYLISTerate{%
  \ifnum \@MYLISTdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@MYLISTdepth\@ne
    \edef\@MYLISTctr{MYLIST\romannumeral\the\@MYLISTdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@MYLISTctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@MYLISTctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
\fi}
\let\endMYLISTerate =\endlist

\newcount\@itemdepth \@itemdepth = 0
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\let\enditemize =\endlist

\makeatother



% Extended MYLISTerate:
%%%\newcounter{MYLISTi}
%%%\setcounter{MYLISTi}{0}
%%%\newcounter{MYLISTii}[MYLISTi]
%%%\newcounter{MYLISTiii}[MYLISTii]
%%%\newcounter{MYLISTiv}[MYLISTiii]
\newcounter{MYLISTv}[MYLISTiv]
\newcounter{MYLISTvi}[MYLISTv]
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTv}{\theMYLISTv.}
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTvi}{\theMYLISTvi.}

% Make the left margins a bit bigger for levels 5 and 6


\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTi}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTii}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTiii}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTiv}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTv}{}
\renewcommand*{\p@MYLISTvi}{}

\renewcommand*{\MYLISTerate}{%
\def\@listi{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmarginii}
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.33\leftmargini}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\itemindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\listparindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\parsep}{1\parskip}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\topsep}{0\parskip plus  0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
}
\def\@listii{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmarginii}
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.33\leftmargini}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\itemindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\listparindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\parsep}{1\parskip}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\topsep}{0\parskip plus  0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
}
\def\@listiii{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmarginiii}
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.33\leftmarginii}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\itemindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\listparindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\parsep}{1\parskip}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\topsep}{0\parskip plus  0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25\parskip}
}
\ifnum \@MYLISTdepth > 5\relax
  \@toodeep
 \else
  \advance\@MYLISTdepth\@ne
  \edef\@MYLISTctr{MYLIST\romannumeral\the\@MYLISTdepth}%
  \expandafter\list\csname label\@MYLISTctr\endcsname{%
     \usecounter\@MYLISTctr
     \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
   }%
\fi
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{textcomp}
% Modify item label formats
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTi}{
\arabic{MYLISTi}\textdegree\large)\normalsize
}
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTii}{
\textbf{\alph{MYLISTii}}\large)\normalsize
}
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTiii}{
\textit{\roman{MYLISTiii}}\large)\normalsize
}
\newcommand*{\labelMYLISTiv}{\theMYLISTiv.}

% Modify the way the item counters are displayed:

\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTi}{\thesection.\arabic{MYLISTi}}
\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTii}{\theMYLISTi.\arabic{MYLISTii}}%
\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTiii}{\theMYLISTii.\arabic{MYLISTiii}}%
\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTiv}{\theMYLISTiii.\arabic{MYLISTiv}}%

% And for the new extended counters:
\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTv}{\theMYLISTiv.\arabic{MYLISTv}}%
\renewcommand*{\theMYLISTvi}{\theMYLISTv.\arabic{MYLISTvi}}%




\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\AtBeginDocument{
\Tag{TITLE+}{MYTITLE}
}
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\def\ClosePar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}
\def\){$\EndPMath}
\def\({\PMath$}
\def\]{$$\EndPMath}
\def\[{\PMath$$}



\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}}{\HCode{</italic>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}}{\HCode{</bold>}}


    \makeatletter

      \ConfigureList{MYLISTerate}%
         {\EndP\HCode{<ol \a:enumerate:\space class="enumerate\expandafter\the\csname @MYLISTdepth\endcsname" \a:LRdir >}\PushMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm=\empty}
         {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm\EndP\HCode{</li></ol>}\ShowPar}
         {\end:itm \gdef\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\DeleteMark}
         {{\Configure{Link}{li}{}{ class="enumerate" id=}{}\let\EndLink=\empty \AnchorLabel }}

\makeatother
\fi

\hrule






enumerate:
\begin{enumerate}
%\setcounter{list1}{4}
\item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item if a rational A is in A,
\begin{enumerate}
\item  if A is negative, it is in A
\item if A is not negative such that its  in A, A is in A; by n; otherwise,
\end{enumerate}
\item for the rLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{enumerate}
\item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{enumerate}


\hrule


MYLISTerate:
\begin{MYLISTerate}
%\setcounter{list1}{4}
\item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\item
\begin{MYLISTerate}
\item if a rational A is in A,
\begin{MYLISTerate}
\item  if A is negative, it is in A
\item if A is not negative such that its  in A, A is in A; by n; otherwise,
\end{MYLISTerate}
\item for the rLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{MYLISTerate}
\item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{MYLISTerate}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we find `alternative4ht.sty`?

Comment: @cfr it is part of [helpers4ht bundle](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht), which is not on CTAN yet