# texh4ht how NOT to print math as images when math is displayed

Tags: math-mode, tex4ht

Edit: I use an extension of `tex4ht`,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

================================

I define a `trivlist2` in order to control the space around `\[` and `\]`.

I want `tex4ht` to take into account my new `trivlist2` and also to use letters in mathmode, such as it uses letters when math is in the text.

I compile with `make4ht -ul hello.tex`.

**Is it possible to have a code which can be put directly into the `.tex` ?**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,
SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}

%\altusepackage{etoolbox}


\newenvironment{trivlist2}
{%
\begin{list}
{}
{
\setlength{\labelwidth}{0ex}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0ex}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0ex}
\setlength{\itemindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\listparindent}{1\parindent}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0ex}
%%il y a \parskip qui s'ajoute a topsep
\setlength{\topsep}{0.1\parskip plus 0\parskip minus 0.1\parskip}
\setlength{\topsep}{0ex}
\setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
%%useless only \topsep counts anyway as there is no \[ ]\ alone in an environment
\setlength{\partopsep}{\parskip}
}}
{\end{list}
}


%\let\oldtrivlist\trivlist
\makeatletter



\renewcommand\[{%
%\relax%
\ifmmode\@badmath%
\else%
%\dotfill
\@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty%
\begin{trivlist2}%
%\@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty
\item[]%
\leavevmode%
\begingroup%
$ %$%
\displaystyle%
\hfill%
\begingroup%
%\par
%\vgl@\nointerlineskip
\nopagebreak%
\fi}

\renewcommand\]{%
\relax
\ifmmode%
%\par
%\vgl@\nointerlineskip
\nopagebreak%
\endgroup%
\hfill%
$ %$%
\endgroup%
%\@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty
\end{trivlist2}%
\@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty%
%\unskip\removelastskip\unskip\removelastskip
\else \@badmath%
\fi}%

\makeatother




\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\AtBeginDocument{
\Tag{TITLE+}{MYTITLE}
}
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\def\ClosePar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}




\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}}{\HCode{</italic>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}}{\HCode{</bold>}}

\fi

\hrule

AAA $a =b$ BBB.
$$ c=d $$
CCC $e=f$ DDDD.
\[ g=h \]
EEEE $i=j$ FFF.

GGG
\[
k=\ell=l
\]




%\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Comment: As mentioned also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284664/tex4ht-configure-a-personal-list-after-the-configuraiton-of-enumerate), posting code nobody can compile is not terribly helpful. If `alternative4ht` is essential, you need to tell us where to get it. Otherwise, omit it from your minimal example (which is not really very minimal).

Comment: @cfr: what can be removed from the example?

Comment: Comment things out and remove them if you can still reproduce the problem. If not, uncomment them again.